# Why does do while loop not work when I press a string other than "y"

Tags: java

```
public class gissa_tal_lek {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object svar = null;
        do {

            Random tal = new Random();
            char s = 's';
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                int nummer = tal.nextInt(5);
                String player1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv in spelare 1 namn: ");

                String player2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv in spelare 2 namn: ");

                String text_p1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hej " + player1 + " ange ett tal mellan 0-5:");
                int p1_tal = Integer.parseInt(text_p1);

                String text_p2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hej " + player2 + " ange ett tal mellan 0-5:");
                int p2_tal = Integer.parseInt(text_p2);

                if (p1_tal == nummer) {
                    String ut_p1 = String.format("%s vann! då %d = %d", player1, p1_tal, nummer);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p1);
                    svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");
                } else if (p2_tal == nummer) {
                    String ut_p2 = String.format("%s vann! då %d = %d", player2, p2_tal, nummer);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p2);
                    svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");
                } else if (p1_tal != nummer && p2_tal != nummer) {
                    String ut_p1_p2_forlora = String.format(
                            " Ingen vann! då %s%c tal är %d\n%s%c tal är %d\nDen korrekta svaret är %d", player1, s,
                            p1_tal, player2, s, p2_tal, nummer);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p1_p2_forlora);
                    svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");
                } else if (p1_tal == nummer && p2_tal == nummer) {
                    String ut_p1_p2_oavgjord = String.format(
                            " Oavgjort! då %s%c tal är %d\n%s%c tal är %d\n Vilket är samma som %d", player1, s, p1_tal,
                            player2, s, p2_tal, nummer);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p1_p2_oavgjord);
                    svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");

                }
            }
        } while (svar.equals("y"));

    }

}
```

This code is a simple game that I made, the problem is that the do-while loop do not work. When I try to press a charachter which is not "y" the code/program should close but it does not do that, any suggest?

Comment: don't use underscores in your class names use CamelCase :)

Comment: You have a `for` loop that runs 5 times before the `while` condition is checked. So the first four y/n answers are ignored.

Comment: Not to your question, but the third `else if` is always true (if reached) and the fourth can never be reached. I, however, am ignorant as to "Oavgjort" so I can't say more (but Google tells me it's a "tie").

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object svar = null;

    Random tal = new Random();
    char s = 's';
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        int nummer = tal.nextInt(5);

        do {
            String player1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv in spelare 1 namn: ");

            String player2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv in spelare 2 namn: ");

            String text_p1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hej " + player1 + " ange ett tal mellan 0-5:");
            int p1_tal = Integer.parseInt(text_p1);

            String text_p2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hej " + player2 + " ange ett tal mellan 0-5:");
            int p2_tal = Integer.parseInt(text_p2);

            if (p1_tal == nummer) {
                String ut_p1 = String.format("%s vann! då %d = %d", player1, p1_tal, nummer);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p1);
                svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");
            } else if (p2_tal == nummer) {
                String ut_p2 = String.format("%s vann! då %d = %d", player2, p2_tal, nummer);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p2);
                svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");
            } else if (p1_tal != nummer && p2_tal != nummer) {
                String ut_p1_p2_forlora = String.format(
                        " Ingen vann! då %s%c tal är %d\n%s%c tal är %d\nDen korrekta svaret är %d", player1, s,
                        p1_tal, player2, s, p2_tal, nummer);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p1_p2_forlora);
                svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");
            } else if (p1_tal == nummer && p2_tal == nummer) {
                String ut_p1_p2_oavgjord = String.format(
                        " Oavgjort! då %s%c tal är %d\n%s%c tal är %d\n Vilket är samma som %d", player1, s, p1_tal,
                        player2, s, p2_tal, nummer);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ut_p1_p2_oavgjord);
                svar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill ni spela igen y/n?");

            }

        }

        while (svar.equals("y"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Spelet är slut");

    }
}

}
```

I solved the problem, I changed the for loop so that the variable i had to either be less or equal to 1, which made the do while loop work. : so instead (for int=0; i<=5;i++) i did (for int i=0; i<=1;i++)

Comment: So you made the for loop completely pointless. Why did you have a for loop there in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

Because you have declared the looping condition as `svar.equals("y")`. 
Check your line

> while (svar.equals("y"));